# ReactJS + Gulp + Reactify + Browserify Element type is invalid: expected a string but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, react-router

I am getting this error:

> bundle.js:26912 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Directory Structure...

```js
.
├── components
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── NavBar.js
│   └── SignIn.js
├── css
│   └── style.css
├── index.html
└── main.js
```

This is my code: **main.js**

```js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Navbar = require("./components/NavBar").default;
var SidePanel = require("./components/index").default;

var App = React.createClass({
 render : function() {
  return (
   <div className="Main">
    <Navbar/>
     <div className="container">
      <SidePanel />
       <div className="row">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  )
 }
});
ReactDOM.render(
 <Router>
  <Route path="/" components={App}/>
 </Router>,
 document.getElementById('app'));
```

My **gulpfile.js**

```js
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect'); //Runs a local dev server
var open = require('gulp-open'); //Open a URL in a web browser
var browserify = require('browserify'); // Bundles JS
var reactify = require('reactify');  // Transforms React JSX to JS
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream'); // Use conventional text streams with Gulp
var concat = require('gulp-concat'); //Concatenates files
// var lint = require('gulp-eslint'); //Lint JS files, including JSX
var babelify = require('babelify'); // support for es6

var config = {
 port: 9005,
 devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
 paths: {
  html: './src/*.html',
  js: './src/**/*.js',
  images: './src/images/*',
  css: [
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
     './src/css/*.css'
     ],
  dist: './dist',
  mainJs: './src/main.js'
 }
}

//Start a local development server
gulp.task('connect', function() {
 connect.server({
  root: ['dist'],
  port: config.port,
  base: config.devBaseUrl,
  livereload: true
 });
});

gulp.task('open', ['connect'], function() {
 gulp.src('dist/index.html')
  .pipe(open('', { url: config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/'}));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
 gulp.src(config.paths.html)
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
  .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
 browserify(config.paths.mainJs)
  //.transform(babelify)
  .transform(reactify)
  .bundle()
  .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/scripts'))
  .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
 gulp.src(config.paths.css)
  .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/css'));
});

// Migrates images to dist folder
// Note that I could even optimize my images here
gulp.task('images', function () {
    gulp.src(config.paths.images)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/images'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());

    //publish favicon
    gulp.src('./src/favicon.ico')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist));
});

// gulp.task('lint', function() {
//  return gulp.src(config.paths.js)
//   .pipe(lint({config: 'eslint.config.json'}))
//   .pipe(lint.format());
// });

gulp.task('watch', function() {
 gulp.watch(config.paths.html, ['html']);
 gulp.watch(config.paths.js, ['js']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'js', 'css', 'images', 'open', 'watch']);
```

**NavBar.js**

```js
var React = require('react');

var Navbar = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return (
   <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
          <div className="container-fluid">
              <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/#authors">Authors</a></li>
                <li><a href="/#about">About</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
   </div>
  );
 }
});

module.exports = Navbar;
```

**index.js**

```js
var React = require("react");
var SignInForm = require("./SignIn");
var SidePanel = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="side-panel">
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <SignInForm />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
module.exports = SidePanel;
```

Using ES5 syntax

Comment: Are you sure that `Navbar` and `SidePanel` returns a valid element?

Comment: Can you paste NavBar and SidePanel's code?

Comment: @try yes, because as soon as i remove the react-route, my component displays perfectly

Comment: are you sure this is the right path?
`var SidePanel = require("./components/index").default;`

Comment: @TMitchell edited just check it out..

Comment: @GiacomoCosimato yes.

Comment: you dont need the '/index' and i believe you dont need the .default as well. Just use var SidePanel = require('./components'); Also its very weird to use index.js file for a component. can you change it to 'SidePanel'? it might create some confusion in the build

Comment: @Kinnza removed still the same error..

Comment: Try not using 'index' file. use a specific name for this plugin. Just a question, can you narrow the problem? can you use just one of them so we'll know the issue is with the sidePanel?

Comment: Also i see SidePanel is using SigninForm. The problem could be there too... Does it has a valid export?

Comment: Is `Route` then a component?

Comment: @TryingToImprove no. its the functionality of react-router to set the path for our component. and I haven't defined it as a component...I am using it to route my component <App/>

Comment: @Kinnza I think the problem here is with react router, as soon as I remove the router then no error...

Comment: Did you see the comment about writing component instead of components in the Router definition? e.g. <Route path="/" component={App}/>

Comment: @Kinnza yup tried that too.. still not working.

Comment: Did you try to simplify things? have the Route with App, but in App dont use any other component, just put a simple Div there. Do you still get the error? If you dont use the router and simply render App does it work?

Comment: @Kinnza ah never mind I redesigned my components, here is the link to the boilerplate - [BoilerPlate](https://github.com/tarangdave/react-boilerplate). Now it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

You have written `components` instead of `component` in the `Route`..

Answer (score 0):

Replace your main.js file with this -

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
var Navbar = require("./components/NavBar");
var SidePanel = require("./components/index");

var App = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div className="Main">
                <Navbar/>
                    <div className="container">
                        <SidePanel />
                            <div className="row">
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
ReactDOM.render((<Router history={browserHistory}><Route path="/" components={App}/></Router>),document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: is **import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router'** ES6 syntax..?? what should I use for ES5?

Comment: @TarangDave You can use `var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory;` for es5

Comment: are you exporting `<SignInForm />` ? and using **browserHistory** in Route ?

Comment: Yes...Signin.js exports SignIpForm which is required by index.js which again uses that <SignInForm/> and exports SidePanel